# Get very specific url

Tags: javascript, url

I want to get very specific string over my url to add as parameter in js:

```
 function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
            apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token=', usuario,
            completado,
            fallo);
        }
```

**URL**

```
http://localhost:55728/Cliente/#/cambiarContrasena.html?Token=e12009cf-d48d-42e7-ba43-83b5082019bb
```

I want to get only Guid afrer `Token=` like:

```
e12009cf-d48d-42e7-ba43-83b5082019bb
```

I try using:

```
   var url = (location.pathname + location.search).substr(1);
    function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
        apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token='+url, usuario,
        completado,
        fallo);
    }
```

But I get

```
http://localhost:55718/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token=Cliente/
```

I try too:

```
var guid = url.substr(url.indexOf('Token=') + 6);
        function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
            apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token='+guid, usuario,
            completado,
            fallo);
        }
```

But I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

What I need to do to get only parameters after Token= ?

I try as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript):

```
 function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) {
                url = window.location.href;
            }
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        function cambiarContrasena(usuario, completado, fallo) {
            apiService.post('/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token='+getParameterByName, usuario,
            completado,
            fallo);
        }
```

But I get an error:

> POST
>   http://localhost:55718/api/usuario/cambiarContrasena?token=function%20getPa…%20%20var%20regex%20=%20new%20RegExp(%22[?&]%22%20+%20name%20+%20%22(=([^&
>   400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: I read it, but I don´t have any idea of how can I implement it @Archer

Comment: I try it as your reference but I still getting error @Archer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this :

```
var url = window.location.hash.split('?Token=')[1];
var guid = url || '';
```

Comment: Problem is that token is dynamic so it can change every post, so I need to read it then apply to url

Comment: @Luis, Hajji's answer works. Please try it before judgement